# Is the "PBUH" suffix used for any women?

Tags: practical-islam, muslim-practices, salawat

I've seen `PBUH` (Peace Be Upon **Him**) added as a suffix to many prominent males who are highly respected in Islam, e.g. Muhammad, Jesus, etc.

My question is whether there are any *women* who have *Peace Be Upon Her* added in a similar fashion, e.g. perhaps the mother of Muhammad or Jesus?

<sub>(I'm not a Muslim, so please treat this as a complete newbie question.)</sub>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this suffix is added to Mary The Virgin (Mariam مريم), the mother of the Prophet Jesus, peace be upon both of them.

It's not added the mother of the Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him).

That is not an exclusion, there might be other women who have that suffix, but I'm not sure about them so I'll try to research and update the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Why the difference between the two mothers?

Comment: @wikis we don't say sallah allah aleha wa salam, we say radiya allahu anha, sallah allahu 3alehum, is for prophet, we don't even use that term for the sahaba But in english it varies than in arabic which is why there are two different answers

Comment: @NesreenA: So what am I missing? The term "peace be upon him" is not identical to صلى الله عليه وسلم but for عليه السلام, not even عليه الصلاة والسلام, although it's believed to be.

Comment: peace be upon them can be used for anyone, but in arabic we say God has sent the blessing upon them, we cant use that for everyone, since we dont know who god send his peace too, Radiya allah anha means god is pleased with her and we cant use that for any women because we don't know who god is pleased with

Comment: @Wikis: In fact it would be the question that "Why is Mary special?", as she is the only special one among prophets' mothers. But why? I can't tell exactly why Allah chose her to be special.

Comment: @NesreenA: please re-read the answer, I didn't say that we can say that suffix to anybody. Also didn't say anything about Radiya Allah Anhu, (I'm just confused why you are objecting to something I didn't say :$).

Comment: Im telling you it can, and the other part was directed to wikis

Comment: @NesreenA: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/5904/discussion-between-tamer-shlash-and-nesreena)

Comment: I may accept this answer if you finish the update you mention in your last sentence. (May => unless a brilliant answer appears in the meantime.)

Comment: This answer is too vague.. it needs edit. By "PBUH" term being the "sallallahu alaihiwasallam", then it is not suffixed for Mariam!

Answer (score 5):

Peace Be Upon Him is generally used for the Prophets (Peace Be Upon Them).

For other people who are highly repected:

'Radi'Allahu Anhu' is used, which means 'Allah's blessings be on him'

OR

'Radi'Allahu Anha' is used for females, which means 'Allah's blessings be on her'.

OR

'Radi'Allahu Anhum' is used for male plural, which means 'Allah's blessings be on them'.

or

'Radi'Allahu Anhuma' is used for female plural, which also means 'Allah's blessings be on them'.

For instance:

- "Abu Bakr (Prophet Muhammad PBUH's Father-in-Law) Radi'Allahu Anhu"
- "Aisha (Prophet Muhammad PBUH's wife) Radi'Allahu Anha"

Comment: I'm puzzled now because there are two contradictory answers.

Answer (score 4):

We have four women most respected in Shia Islam:

1. Fatimah سلام الله علیها, daughter of the holy Prophet صل الله علیه و آله
2. Khadijeh سلام الله علیها, wife of the holy Prophet صل الله علیه و آله and mother of Fatimah سلام االه علیها
3. Virgin Mary سلام الله علیها, the mother of Jesus علیه السلام
4. Asiyeh سلام الله علیها, wife of pharaoh and she believed in Moses while hiding her belief from her husband (she may be considered also the Moses' stepmother, when she took him from the river)

There are many who we can send سلام الله toward, but there are some people that we should do this as neglecting this may be somewhat a disrespect.

Comment: Is that the same as PBUH?

Comment: Yes, if you translate Salam as Peace.

Answer (score 2):

Peace be upon him can be used for anyone, that just means you would like to send peace to someone. It like the saying rest in peace.

What muslims say is Sallah Allahu alehe wa salam, Which is much different that peace be upon him, it actually means may Allah send our prayer and peace to him.

For this reason we don't use it for anyone but the prophets, in our prayers we include the prophets. There is many arguements as to who exactly this can be used for. Some say it is exclusivly for Prophet muhammad (SAAW) others include Prophet abraham And others say all prophets in general. But it is agreed that it dosen't go beyond prophets.

What we use for people other than prophets is "Radiya allahu anhum," which menas Allah is pleased with them. We only use this for people of high honor, and close to the prophet, (including women) such as:

- The sahaba ( the friends and companions of the prophet)
- Mary
- Asiya (pharohs wife)
- The prophet's wives etc.

As for the prophets mother, we do not give this title, becasue we do not know whether Allah was pleased with her or not, as we are not given any mention of her in quran or hadith as the others listed above are.

Answer (score -1):

`Peace be upon him` is reserved for prophets only specifically for Hazrat Muhammad (Peace be upon Him). Best practice is, it should not be used for anyone else, including any women.

In Islam different figures have different titles. These actually come from Arabic. Peace be Upon him is just one version of translation. The correct titles are

```
Prophet Muhammad -صلى الله عليه وآله وسلم Sallalaho Alaihi wa AalihiWasallam

Jesus, Moses, Ibrahim and all others - عليه السلام Alai Salam

Early Followers of the prophet who personally saw him - رضی الله تعالیٰ عنہ Raziulll tala unho

This is not distinction between men, women, children including children of the prophet in the above title, all are treated the same.

Great Muslim scholars who came later, did not see the prophet - Rehmatullah Alai
```

So in short Peace be upon his/her is never used with a woman.

In english we do see the name PBUH is used with Jesus Christ and seldom with Bibi Maryam. This is actually wrong. I think Muslim scholars use this just to attract sympathy from Christian brothers + show respect to them as well. They should not have this title, only prophet Muhammad has this title.

So no woman can have this title. In the woman who has the highest rank is suppose to be, Bibi Fatima (RA). She is the daughter of prophet Muhammad. We do not use PBUH with her. She has the regular title as any other follower has.

Correction for Muslims:  It is wrong to use PBUH with Bibi Maryam because she was not a prophet.

Also we do not use any title with the mother of the prophet herself. But she is treated with respect, nevertheless. Her name is Aminah Bibi.

Comment: what is "bibi"?

Comment: @NesreenA [bibi](http://shabdkosh.raftaar.in/Hindi-Dictionary/Meaning/bibi) is a hindi/urdu term used to address women with respect.